# Prove that there exists a linear equation $ax+by=c$ which has $m$ solutions

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Prove that for every positive integer $m$ there exists a linear equation  $ax+by=c$  which has exactly  $m$ positive integer solutions.

So for this problem, I tried to find the integer solutions for both $x$ and $y$. I wasn't quite sure how to solve it but I was able to produce something akin to a solution:

Theorem:

> Let $d=(a,b)$, then $ax+by=c$ has $m$ solutions only if $d \mid c$.

Since $d=(a,b)$, we have $d=am+bn$ for some integers $m$ and $n$. After this I was a bit lost on how to continue on with this but what I was going to do was create another variable place holder to set equal to $c =d \times \text{placeholder}$. So, my question is, what kind of beautiful proofs does stack exchange have for this problem?

Comment: Can you state the problem more precisely?  Are all the variables required to be integers?  Nonnegative integers?

Comment: Makes no sense.  The equation must be a line.  If a line has two integer solutions it has a rational slope and infinite integer solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Over the integers, any equation $ax+by=c$ has either none or infinitely many solutions. So I'll assume that $a,b$ are positive integers and that you are looking for positive integer solutions.

Let us look at equations $ax+by=1$, where $(a,b)=1$. Given a solution $x_0,y_0$ (that can be found with the Euclidean Algorithm), the general solution is 
$$
x_n=x_0+bn,\ \ y_n=y_0-an. 
$$
Note that necessarily one of $x_0,y_0$ is positive and the other is negative. Let us assume that $x_0<0$, $y_0>0$. 
To have positive solutions we need 
$$
x_0+bn>0,\ \ \ y_0-an>0, 
$$
which translate into 
$$
-\frac{x_0}b<n<\frac{y_0}a.
$$
So the number of positive solutions is 
$$
\left\lceil \frac{y_0}a+\frac{x_0}b-1\right\rceil
$$
(the weird expression accounts for the fact the behaviour is different depending on whether the sum is an integer or not). 
For instance take $a=1$, $b=2$, $x_0=-2m-2$, $y_0=2m+2$. Then 
$$
ax_0+by_0=-2m-2+4m+4=2m+2. 
$$
And 
$$
\frac{y_0}a+\frac{x_0}b-1=\frac{2m+2}1+\frac{-2m-2}2-1=m.
$$
That is, if $a=1$, $b=2$, $c=2m+2$, then $ax+by=c$ has $m$ positive integer solutions.

Comment: This means that at least one of $x$ or $y$ must be even, because we are counting *positive integer* solutions.